# numpy, array arithmetic shows invalid syntax after iterating over said array

Tags: python, syntax-error, numpy-ndarray

I am trying to write this function that creates kernels for kernel convolution.

And I'm converting the result from range -1,1 to range 0,1

```python
def generate(phaseX, freqX, phaseY, freqY, shape):
    img = numpy.full(shape, 0.5, dtype=numpy.float32)

    for x in range(shape[0]):
        for y in range(shape[0]):
            img[x,y] *= numpy.cos(x*freqX+phaseX) * (numpy.cos(y*freqY+phaseY)

    img = (img*0.5)+0.5
    return img
```

Here I get an error:

```
   File "c:\Users\martin\Documents\rt3s\dct.py", line 40
    img = (img*0.5)+0.5
    ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

And when I remove the for loops the error disappears.

I'm thinking that the iteration is somehow changing the type, but I've never encountered this problem, and I don't know how to go about investigating what is happening.
with that said, what is happening here?

Comment: As usual, you've got a missing parenthesis. (Also, the error message you posted cannot have come from the code you posted.)

Comment: @user2357112supportsMonica ah I've missed that, that explains it lmao, and yeah I've used the smallest code I had that was exhibiting the error, but forgot to copy out the error message, my bad.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was caused by superfluous parenthesis,
removing it has fixed the issue.

```
for x in range(shape[0]):
    for y in range(shape[0]):
        img[x,y] *= numpy.cos(x*freqX+phaseX) * numpy.cos(y*freqY+phaseY)
```